# Windows cannot access the specified device, file... error when running exe made using PyInstaller

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller

I am facing an issue while converting my kivy app to an executable file using PyInstaller. While building the exe and running it on my device, I don't face any kind of issue, but when I move it to another device it is throwing following error:

> Windows cannot access the specified device, path or file. You may not have the appropriate permission to access the item.

```
PyInstaller = 6.1.0
Python = 3.11
```

Here are the commands I am using to create the exe file:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole --uac-admin --name=PrinterManager --icon=logo.png main.py > build.log 2>&1

python edit_specs.py
pyinstaller PrinterManager.spec > exe.log 2>&1
```

I don't know why this issue started occurring right now, as I am using the same commands to make the exe in past and those are working perfectly fine. Also the strange thing is that when earlier I used to make these exes, it would be significantly larger (145 MB) but now it is much smaller (87 MB), but I can't be sure if this is related to the issue at hand, because I have done different changes in the app which can cause this size reduction.

The things I have tried till now is:

- Adding `--add-binary 'c:/python311/python311.dll;.'` in the first command
- Removing `--uac-admin`
- Removing `--icon=logo.png`

None of this helped me thus far, so if anyone has any idea, then please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually resolved this issue by following this thread on github [python .dll not found in virtual enviornment](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3942#issuecomment-449809240).

I am still unclear on how to resolve this issue so it works with virtual env enabled. But this still solves the issue so I would add it over here for anyone facing the same issue.

If someone has a good explanation to this please share in your own answer or edit this answer for better understanding.